# Parse JSON string to an existing object without allocating new object

Tags: javascript

Due to the dynamic nature of my application, it’s possible to load a lot of localStorage data. The problem is that I’m creating a lot of new objects and throwing away the old ones, causing the GC to work more. Is there a way to parse a JSON string to an existing object instead of creating a new one?

Edit: Clarification

I’m creating a game where there is procedural terrain generation. This data is then saved when “chunks” are out of the viewport and replaced with new data. The problem is that this new data is coming from stringified JSON from localStorage, which is allocating a new object every time I parse the data. I would rather have a set amount of objects representing about 5 “chunks” that would get reused.

I cannot use the old object since it has irrelevant data, so I need a way to parse stringified JSON in a manner that reuses this old object instead of allocating a new one since JSON.parse creates a new object.

Comment: I think you should solve the "creating a lot of new objects and throwing away the old ones" problem instead of working around it.

Comment: Why do you create a new object instead of creating a reusable List of Objects ? and pop unnecessary objects ..

Comment: @Joseph It’s a game that infinitely generates and saves terrain in two directions. I don’t think loading the entire world data into memory is practical

Comment: @CristiC777 The necessary data is coming from localStorage. They’re stringified JSON objects. I could copy the values from the parsed data to the reusable one, but either way it’s still going to leave a wasted extra object simply due to the nature of JSON.parse which allocates an entirely new object from the string.

Answer (score 0):

Using [org.json](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json) library:

```
try 
{
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("{\"Name\":\"Domz\",\"wp\":\"inst\"}");
}catch (JSONException err){
 Log.d("Error", err.toString());
}
```

Or One More Way

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(stringToParse);
```